# action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build() works on windows but doesn't work on linux

Tags: java, linux, selenium

`action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build()` works fine on windows but doesn't work on linux. I am writing a testcase using selenium webdriver and I am trying to select all the text which is written in a rich textbox and have used this code snippet to perform the select all command.It works fine on windows on firefox 38 browser but when I run my testcases on jenkins machine which is a linux machine,browser is firefox(don't know the exact version but above version 33) this code snippet doesn't work.I have tried some alternatives like `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));` and double click on rich textbox to select the text written in it but nothing works.What could be the reason,why these code snippets are not working on linux machine.

Comment: i think i wont get an answer here.where are all the bullies who come here to make fun of noobs.Why dont they come forward and provide a solution for the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question `action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build()` and `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,` "a"));was not running on Linux machine Firefox browser because the native events were not enabled in my driver factory.To enable Native Events you need to write the following code in the driver factory i.e where the required driver is created

```
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: for further reference go through this https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions